# Does Derf see something in Dahmer's House?

Tags: plot-explanation, my-friend-dahmer

Towards the end of *My Friend Dahmer*, Derf drives Dahmer home and they go into his house for a beer, but once inside Derf freezes, staring straight ahead - he then makes his excuses and leaves.

Did he see something in Dahmer's house that made him leave or did he just get nervous about being alone in a dark house with his former friend? - the way Derf acted suggested the former.